# Click Once deployed application on Windows XP SP2

Tags: .net, deployment, clickonce

We have WinForm application targetting .NET Framework 3.0.

After installing such application using ClickOnce deployement on XP SP2 machine application cant be started. After opening such application the "Launching Application" windows appears and then nothing, no msg box, no error, just nothing happens. Installation goes ok, it just cant be started, and application works well on XP SP3, Vista and Win7.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to sound odd, but does the client machine have a Kensington mouse driver installed?  We were experiencing the same symptoms with a click once application a couple years ago, and it turned out to be an issue with Kensington mouse drivers.  Uninstall them and use the generic Windows driver.

There are several sites / posts discussing this issue, including this one: http://www.scicomp.dk/node/14

Comment: No, there is no mouse driver installed. We got the same error in Virtual Machine where we test it. The prereqs for app are DirectX, .NET and win installer and we have bootstrapers for that. Installation goes ok, just nothing happens when we start it in XP sp2.

Answer (score 0):

To log ClickOnce errors, create a string value called `LogFilePath` in the Registry Key `HKEY_Current_User\Software\Classes\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Deployment`, and set its value to the filepath of your log, e.g. `C:\temp\ClickOnceErrors.txt`.

Does that give any clues?

Answer (score 0):

First check the ClickOnce cache and see if there are files there. It sounds like it is installing it fine. The problem is most likely (99% of these cases) that your application is crashing before it can show it.

Try putting a message box or something in the very first part of your application and deploy and install it -- do you see the messagebox? Or add some logging. Or *something*.

Are you handling the Unhandled Exception exception for your application?